# jQuery bug - Cannot proceed without uploading image

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page I am building allows the user to add a new product to the system. I have a jQuery issue with this page where the page wont let me proceed unless I upload a photo - which should not happen, the customer should be able to proceed without uploading a photo for the item.  There is a textbox for Product name, product item code, a dropdown for categories and an upload for an image. I need to put in place some code to allow the finish button to be clicked without an image being uploaded. Here is my code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
    autoUpload: false,
    singleFileUploads: false,
    replaceFileInput: false,
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        $('#previews').empty();
    $("#finish").off('click').on('click', function () {
        var sku = $("#productSKU").val();
        var name = $("#productName").val();
        var affiliateId = $("#AffiliateID").val();
        var Errors = "";
        var category = null;
        var defaultName = $('#defaultImgName').val();

        if ($("#childCategories_" + categoryLevel).length == 0) {
            category = $("#categoryList").val();
        }
        else if ($("#childCategories_" + categoryLevel).val() == 0) {
            category = null;
        }
        else {
            category = $("#childCategories_" + categoryLevel).val();
        }

        if (!sku) {
            Errors += "<li> You can not add a product without an Item Code</li>";
        }
        if (!name) {
            Errors += "<li> You can not add a product without a Name</li>";
        }
        if (!category) {
            Errors += "<li> You can not add a product without a Category</li>";
        }

        if (Errors != "") {
            cua({ text: Errors, type: 'danger' })
        }
        else {
            data.formData = { productName: name, productSKU: sku, affiliateID: affiliateId, categoryID: category, defaultImgName: defaultName }
            data.submit();
        }
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $('#previews');

    node.append("<div class=\"img-preview\"></div>");
    var innernode = node.find('.img-preview').last();
    innernode.append(file.preview);
    innernode.attr('data-name', file.name);

    var firstImg = node.find('.img-preview').first();
    $('.default-img').removeClass('default-img');
    firstImg.addClass('default-img');
    $('#defaultImgName').val($('.default-img').data('name'));

    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"></span>').text(file.error));
    }
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    if (data.result != false) {
        cua({ text: 'Successfully added new item', type: 'success' });
        closeAddNew();
    }
});
```

I have tried to debug it with my chrome developer tools but its still difficult isolating this problem. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate the validation for image and other input fields validation.
Hope it helps, thanks ;)